# Concrete5 store won't allow me to input credit card details

Tags: forms, concrete5

I am setting up a site in Concrete5. I have installed the Community Marketplace and the Square integration.  From there I added a product which allows people to buy a level of membership, giving them access to certain pages.

When I go through to test it, I am permitted to put in my address and phone number, but when i comes to inputting the credit card details I don't get any input boxes, just the form labels which change the mouse pointer to a finger icon.  Clicking the labels does nothing.

Does anyone know why it would be doing this?

Comment: "From there I added a product which" - do you mean you bought an addon?

Comment: No, I mean a created/listed a "product" in the store.  In this case, it simply moves the purchaser to a new membership level, which allows access to more pages.